# Get array of strings on specific words

Tags: php

I'm trying to split a string into an array on specific words like Tab Inj etc

```
Tab. Vilda 50Mg Daily, 30 Mins Before Breakfast 
T0 Mins Before Breakfast  Once Daily At 8 P.M.
Tab Atchol 20. Once Daily At 10 P.M.
-Tab Aktiv D 60K Units Once In 15 Days With Milk At Bed Time
-Inj Denosumab 60Mg Stat(26/04/23)
-Tab. Pth 30Mg One  Tablet Every Alternate  Daily At 10Pm
```

```
[
 'Tab. Vilda 50Mg Daily, 30 Mins Before Breakfast T0 Mins Before Breakfast  Once Daily At 8 P.M.',
 'Tab Atchol 20. Once Daily At 10 P.M.',
 'Tab Aktiv D 60K Units Once In 15 Days With Milk At Bed Time',
 'Inj Denosumab 60Mg Stat(26/04/23)',
 'Tab. Pth 30Mg One  Tablet Every Alternate  Daily At 10Pm'
]
```

Try exploding the string and appending certain words to them but it didn't work. Any advice how I can use regex to achieve this?

Comment: I think that free text input and matching for critical patient information like this is a recipe for a life-threatening disaster. Someone mis-types 'inj' or 'tab' and a dose is missed or doubled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
<?php
$input = "Tab. Vilda 50Mg Daily, 30 Mins Before Breakfast 
T0 Mins Before Breakfast  Once Daily At 8 P.M.
Tab Atchol 20. Once Daily At 10 P.M.
-Tab Aktiv D 60K Units Once In 15 Days With Milk At Bed Time
-Inj Denosumab 60Mg Stat(26/04/23)
-Tab. Pth 30Mg One  Tablet Every Alternate  Daily At 10Pm";
$split = preg_split(
    '/(tab|inj)/i',
    $input,
    -1,
    PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE
);
$fixed = [];
foreach (array_chunk($split, 2) as $item) {
    $fixed[] = implode('', $item);
}

var_dump($fixed);
```

Outputs:

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(98) "Tab. Vilda 50Mg Daily, 30 Mins Before Breakfast 
T0 Mins Before Breakfast  Once Daily At 8 P.M.
"
  [1]=>
  string(39) "Tab Atchol 20. Once Daily At 10 P.M.
-"
  [2]=>
  string(62) "Tab Aktiv D 60K Units Once In 15 Days With Milk At Bed Time
-"
  [3]=>
  string(36) "Inj Denosumab 60Mg Stat(26/04/23)
-"
  [4]=>
  string(19) "Tab. Pth 30Mg One  "
  [5]=>
  string(37) "Tablet Every Alternate  Daily At 10Pm"
}
```

Though, as @Sammitch said in the comments, there is a high probability that something will go wrong. Even in this case, you have "Tab" in "Tablet", so it put that into its own item in the array. You can make corrections to the regex such as:

```php
$split = preg_split(
    '/(tab[\s\.]|inj[\s\.])/i', // Only match 'tab' or 'inj' if there is whitespace or a period afterwards
    $input,
    -1,
    PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE
);
```

To get the result:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(98) "Tab. Vilda 50Mg Daily, 30 Mins Before Breakfast 
T0 Mins Before Breakfast  Once Daily At 8 P.M.
"
  [1]=>
  string(39) "Tab Atchol 20. Once Daily At 10 P.M.
-"
  [2]=>
  string(62) "Tab Aktiv D 60K Units Once In 15 Days With Milk At Bed Time
-"
  [3]=>
  string(36) "Inj Denosumab 60Mg Stat(26/04/23)
-"
  [4]=>
  string(56) "Tab. Pth 30Mg One  Tablet Every Alternate  Daily At 10Pm"
}
```

But if the information is critical in how it is parsed, I'd be concerned too.

Comment: Thank you it worked. Also it's not for the patient. Its scraped from a website which is public data not critical patient information.

Comment: Awesome, glad it worked! And nice to know it isn't critical.